# How to display all values of a custom field in a given category?

Tags: custom-fields

In a WordPress category that has posts in it, each post has a custom field that has a value (usually a number).

The question:

How do I get all the custom field values from all the posts from that category? 
(I want to be able to use those values independently (to strip non-numerical characters, make average, etc).

Thank you,

Puiu D. - Romania

Answer (score 0):

`get_post_custom` returns a multidimensional array with all custom fields of a particular post or page.

**EG:**

```
$custom_fields = get_post_custom($post_id);
```

You can get all your posts in a specific category using `get_posts` and loop through them to get their specific custom fields.

Function Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom